# jqxNumberInput 'val' method

Tags: javascript

Can somebody bring a clean example of how to read value from jqxNumberInput?

whatever I do trying to read value by `jqxNumberInput('val');` - I'm getting zero.

Comment: You should add the code you are using that returns you a zero.

Comment: var Val = $("#inptMyInput").jqxNumberInput('val');                                               Val is always zero regardless what is in the control.

Comment: ops. the control was declared in HTML like :                                                            <div id='inptMyInput'><input style='float: none; width:100px;' type="text" />   now i see that <input > tag is what cause the problem.                                        Thanks for guess!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
var price = $('#dlgPartEditEdtPrice').jqxNumberInput('getDecimal');
```